# Swift: check empty array

Tags: arrays, swift, arraylist

```
array = [
    “test” = test
    “test1” = test
    “test2” = test  
    “test4” = test  
]
```

Check if test3 is in the array

I tried to do this:

```
if let check= userObject[“test3”]{

}
```

My app crashes and I get this error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Aren't you getting error on your array declaration?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have commas separating your objects, and that's a dictionary, not an array.

```
var dict: [String: AnyObject] = [:]

dict = [
    "test": test,
    "test1": test,
    "test2": test,  
    "test4": test 
]
```